# Installing ViennaCL on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, shared-libraries, opencl, viennacl

I have successfully built ViennaCL using `cmake .` and `make` and run some of its generated tests on Ubuntu 11.04. But how do I install it and how do I include and link it with my application? Shouldn't it generate headers and shared libraries that automatically installs under `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`? The Makefile doesn't contain any `install` target.

/Nordlöw

Comment: When using CMake I think it is advised to use a build directory so you don't clutter up your source directory. e.g. mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; make

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViennaCL is a header/template library. All you need to do is copy the viennacl directory wherever you want to install the headers and you are done. This is clearly explained in the README file that accompanies the distribution:

> ViennaCL is a header-only library,
>   therefore it is sufficient to copy the
>   subfolder ViennaCL/ (holding the
>   header files) into you project
>   directory or your system include
>   directory.

You should note that the subfolder mentioned in the README is actually named viennacl (lower case) in recent versions.